# DiffUtil Callback resulting in index out of bounds exception

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, rx-java2

I am currently developing a list of items that has 4 fields that can be edited with an autocomplete feature. The underlying data structure is a list of pairs of the 4 fields and their autocomplete suggestions. Before the user edits the suggestions are empty once the user edits a request is fired and i use a diffutil to detect & dispatch the changes to the adapter. I am using the redux/mvi pattern, so i calculate the diffutil call back in the view model then pass a pair to my activity to just dispatch the changes. 
Time for some code and error snippets :)

Error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{88b1b52 position=5 id=-1, oldPos=0, pLpos:0 scrap [attachedScrap] tmpDetached no parent} android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView{c60ba82 VFED..... ......I. 11,11-1069,990 #7f0900ba app:id/rv_suggestions}, adapter:com.accenture.shiny.screens.classify.ClassifyActivity$setupRecyclerView$1@8f3593, layout:android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager@1fec9d0, context:com.accenture.shiny.screens.classify.ClassifyActivity@9caa09a
```

DiffUtil:

```
class ClassificationDiffCallback(private val oldList: Pair<MutableList<ItemInfo>, AutoCompleteResponse>,
                             private val newList: Pair<MutableList<ItemInfo>, AutoCompleteResponse>) : DiffUtil.Callback() {

override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
        oldList.first!![oldItemPosition].getData<Classification>().id == newList.first!![newItemPosition].getData<Classification>().id


override fun getOldListSize() = oldList.first?.size!!


override fun getNewListSize() = newList.first?.size!!


override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int) =
        newList.first!![newItemPosition].getData<Pair<Classification, AutoCompleteResponse>>() == oldList.first!![oldItemPosition].getData<Pair<Classification, AutoCompleteResponse>>()


override fun getChangePayload(oldItemPosition: Int, newItemPosition: Int): Any? {
    return newList.first!![newItemPosition].getData<Pair<Classification, AutoCompleteResponse>>().second
}
}
```

ViewModel state reduction:

```
 val currentEditableState = (currentState as EditableClassifyState)
                    val list = currentEditableState.classificationsItemInfoDiffResultPair.first
                    EditableClassifyState(calculateClassificationsDiffResultPair(
                            Observable.fromIterable(list ?: mutableListOf())
                                    .map { itemInfo ->
                                        val classification = when (itemInfo.getData<Any>()) {
                                            is Pair<*, *> -> itemInfo.getData<Pair<Any, DiffUtil.DiffResult>>().first
                                            else -> Unit
                                        }
                                        ItemInfo(Pair(classification, result),
                                                if (classification === Unit) R.layout.manual_classification else R.layout.classification_item_layout)
                                                .setId((classification as? Classification)?.id
                                                        ?: 0)
                                    }.toList().blockingGet(), result))


fun calculateClassificationsDiffResultPair(list: MutableList<ItemInfo>, result: AutoCompleteResponse = AutoCompleteResponse()): Pair<MutableList<ItemInfo>, DiffUtil.DiffResult> {
    return Flowable.fromArray(list)
            .scan(Pair(mutableListOf(), DiffUtil.calculateDiff(ClassificationDiffCallback(Pair(mutableListOf(), AutoCompleteResponse()), Pair(mutableListOf(), AutoCompleteResponse())))))
            { state: Pair<MutableList<ItemInfo>, DiffUtil.DiffResult>, next: MutableList<ItemInfo> ->
                Pair(next, DiffUtil.calculateDiff(ClassificationDiffCallback(Pair(state.first, result), Pair(next, result))))
            }
            .skip(1)
            .blockingFirst()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Never use !! with Kotlin. Never.

Comment: You can use [ListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) from the support library, it handles diffing on a background thread for you.

Comment: @Demigod well there are times when it makes sense but generally no

Answer (score 2):

`DiffUtils` compares two objects that is not empty.
So if the `newList` and `oldList` are either empty call `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of calling `DiffUtil`

I'm not familiar with the library you used, but I've already encounter this kind of problem before.

Comment: what library are you referring to ?

Comment: @ZeyadGasser rxjava

Answer (score 0):

I observed the bug for:

```
adapter.items = newItems
val result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
    AllModulesDiffUtilsCallback(oldItems, newItems)
)
result.dispatchUpdatesTo(this)
```

and overriden `Adapter#setItems()`:

```
override fun setItems(items: List<RecyclerItem>) {
    this.items = when (state) {
        State.COLLAPSED -> items.take(4)
        State.EXPANDED -> items
    }
}
```

Exception happened, because `adapter#items` count is different than `newItems` for `COLLAPSED`, after such operation. They should be the same data though.

Apart from that, watch out for `override fun getItemCount(): Int` - overriding it may have similar effect.